# Unwanted route suggested by Maps App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I'm using this code to launch Maps for a route between current location and a selected destination in driving mode:

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:dest.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem * destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark: placemark];
destination.name = @"Point of interest";
NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destination, nil];
NSDictionary* options = @{MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey : @(MKMapTypeStandard),
                          MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems: items launchOptions: options];
```

Unfortunately, Maps suggests a walking route as an alternative, as evident in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to hide this walking route?

I'm targeting iOS 7.